# Обработчик отправки фото

Tags: php, email

В существующем обработчике отправки сообщения на электронный адрес отсутствует возможность отправить фотографию.

Веб-форма на странице HTML:

```
    <form id="myform" method="post" action="process.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    .... // инпуты текстовых полей

   /* Я добавил */
    <label for="file">Прикрепить фото:</label>
    <input id="file" name="file" type="file">

    /* кнопка */
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить">
    </form>
```

Обработчик текстовых полей:

```
<?php if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    header( "Location: index.html" );
  }

.... // обработка текстовых полей
.... // переменные заголовков

/* функция маил */
mail ($your_email, $subject, $email_body, "From: $nam <$ema>" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: $nam <$ema>" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
```

*Все текстовые поля обрабатываются и отправляются на эл.почту.*

Помогите пожалуйста добавить в обработчик отправки на эл.почту фотографию в формате jpg, png весом не больше 1-го мегабайта.

Comment: Добавил еще вариант вставки картинки в емэйл.

Answer (score 1):

Отправка файлов емэйлом дело очень геморойное. Лучше использовать библиотеку.
Например:

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();
...
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.jpg');
...
if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

или

http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mail.message.html

или

https://www.google.ca/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php%20mail%20library

**Еще один вариант:**
Если тело емэйла HTML добавить картинку сразу в тэг. Из недостатков размер картинки увеличиться на ~ 30%

Comment: ни одна библиотека не подходит для моего обработчика отправки сообщения. СПС